# Getting Shipping Rate On Product View Page

Tags: magento

How do you get the shipping rate on the product view page for Magento Community 1.5.01?

I've been googling for about 4 hours, i've tried all suggested solutions on the first 10 pages for the phrase "magento shipping rate on product view page", nothing is working.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you are using Table rate?

Comment: Shipping Rates mainly rely on the Shipping Address of the Customer ordering the product in the Checkout Onepage. So, I don't think that you will be able to find any solution to this requirement, since when a Customer is viewing the product details page, Magento will not provide the shipping rate by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to display shipping rate then you can use below code for title and price:

Display flatrate title:
Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/flatrate/title');

Dislay flatrate price:
Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/flatrate/price')

Enjoy!!!!!!